# Inner Select Statement Help - Subqueries?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join

I've been trying to create a simple productivity dashboard report for our business needs and running into issues on how to get this done.

There are 7 tasks that the users need to complete in an order. I want to show one line, showing each completed dates but they are showing up as different line items.

How do I make it show as one line item? Here's the code I built:

```
select 

o.Number as 'OrderNo',
s.FullName as 'CPC Emp',
case when t.description='Loan Package to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as 'Loan Pck To Lender',
case when t.description='Recording Audit' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as 'Recording Audit',
case when t.description='Recorded Docs' then rt.RequestedDate else NULL end as 'Recorded Docs Requested',
case when t.description='Recorded Docs to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
case when t.description='Recorded Docs to Purchaser' then t.CompletedDate else null end as 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
case when t.description='Title Policy to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as 'TP to Lender',
case when t.description='Title Policy to Purchaser' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as 'TP Purchaser'

FROM pf.OrderInfo oi
    INNER JOIN pfm.[Order] o
            on (o.RootId# = oi.rootid)
    INNER JOIN core.Profile op
        ON (oi.OwningProfileID = op.ID)
    INNER JOIN zref.OrderStatus os
        ON (oi.OrderStatus = os.ID)
    INNER JOIN zref.ProductType pt
            on (o.ProductTypeID = pt.ID and pt.ID <>'15')
    INNER JOIN pfm.Task t
        ON (t.RootId# = oi.RootID 
        and (t.Description in ('Loan Package to Lender','Recording Audit','Recorded Docs to Lender',
        'Recorded Docs to Purchaser', 'Title Policy to Lender','Title Policy to Purchaser','Recorded Docs')     
        ) )         
    left outer JOIN pfm.RequestedTask rt    
        ON (rt.RootId# = t.RootId# and rt.Id#=t.Id# and rt.LastId# = t.LastId#)
    left outer JOIN core.SecurityIdentity s
        ON (s.ID = t.CompletedByID)

WHERE 
(op.Name like 'BH104%' -- Profiles Begin.
or op.name like 'WO115%' --Profiles End.
)
and t.CompletedDate between '2016-1-1' and '2016-4-30'
and s.fullname is not null

group by s.fullname, o.Number, t.Description, t.CompletedDate, rt.RequestedDate

order by 2 desc
```

Top 10 result is shown as below:
[image: result]

How do I make it show one line item on those red box results? Any help would be greatly appreciate it.. I tried inner select statements and subqueries but was unable to get that working..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each row for an order only contains values for one column, then the result set becomes a sparse matrix which could be reduced with an aggregate function such as `MAX`:

```
select 

o.Number as 'OrderNo',
s.FullName as 'CPC Emp',
MAX(case when t.description='Loan Package to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as) 'Loan Pck To Lender',
MAX(case when t.description='Recording Audit' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end) as 'Recording Audit',
MAX(case when t.description='Recorded Docs' then rt.RequestedDate else NULL end) as 'Recorded Docs Requested',
MAX(case when t.description='Recorded Docs to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end) as 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
MAX(case when t.description='Recorded Docs to Purchaser' then t.CompletedDate else null end) as 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
MAX(case when t.description='Title Policy to Lender' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end as) 'TP to Lender',
MAX(case when t.description='Title Policy to Purchaser' then t.CompletedDate else NULL end) as 'TP Purchaser'

FROM pf.OrderInfo oi
    INNER JOIN pfm.[Order] o
            on (o.RootId# = oi.rootid)
    INNER JOIN core.Profile op
        ON (oi.OwningProfileID = op.ID)
    INNER JOIN zref.OrderStatus os
        ON (oi.OrderStatus = os.ID)
    INNER JOIN zref.ProductType pt
            on (o.ProductTypeID = pt.ID and pt.ID <>'15')
    INNER JOIN pfm.Task t
        ON (t.RootId# = oi.RootID 
        and (t.Description in ('Loan Package to Lender','Recording Audit','Recorded Docs to Lender',
        'Recorded Docs to Purchaser', 'Title Policy to Lender','Title Policy to Purchaser','Recorded Docs')     
        ) )         
    left outer JOIN pfm.RequestedTask rt    
        ON (rt.RootId# = t.RootId# and rt.Id#=t.Id# and rt.LastId# = t.LastId#)
    left outer JOIN core.SecurityIdentity s
        ON (s.ID = t.CompletedByID)

WHERE 
(op.Name like 'BH104%' -- Profiles Begin.
or op.name like 'WO115%' --Profiles End.
)
and t.CompletedDate between '2016-1-1' and '2016-4-30'
and s.fullname is not null

group by s.fullname, o.Number

order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Wow, great to know!! This should be what I needed.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
;WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT o.Number AS 'OrderNo'
            , s.FullName AS 'CPC Emp'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Loan Package to Lender' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Loan Pck To Lender'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Recording Audit' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Recording Audit'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs' THEN rt.RequestedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Recorded Docs Requested'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Lender' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Recorded Docs to Lender'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Lender' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'TP to Lender'
            , CASE
                WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Purchaser' THEN t.CompletedDate
                ELSE NULL
             END AS 'TP Purchaser'
        FROM   pf.OrderInfo oi
             INNER JOIN pfm.[Order] o ON o.RootId# = oi.rootid
             INNER JOIN core.Profile op ON oi.OwningProfileID = op.ID
             INNER JOIN zref.OrderStatus os ON oi.OrderStatus = os.ID
             INNER JOIN zref.ProductType pt ON o.ProductTypeID = pt.ID
                                        AND pt.ID <> '15'
             INNER JOIN pfm.Task t ON t.RootId# = oi.RootID
                                 AND t.Description IN('Loan Package to Lender', 'Recording Audit', 'Recorded Docs to Lender', 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser', 'Title Policy to Lender', 'Title Policy to Purchaser', 'Recorded Docs')
             LEFT OUTER JOIN pfm.RequestedTask rt ON rt.RootId# = t.RootId#
                                             AND rt.Id# = t.Id#
                                             AND rt.LastId# = t.LastId#
             LEFT OUTER JOIN core.SecurityIdentity s ON s.ID = t.CompletedByID
        WHERE  (op.Name LIKE 'BH104%' -- Profiles Begin.
              OR op.name LIKE 'WO115%' --Profiles End.
             )
             AND t.CompletedDate BETWEEN '2016-1-1' AND '2016-4-30'
             AND s.fullname IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY s.fullname
             , o.Number
             , t.Description
             , t.CompletedDate
             , rt.RequestedDate)
    SELECT CTE.OrderNo
        , CTE.[CPC Emp]
        , [Loan Pck To Lender]=MAX(CTE.[Loan Pck To Lender])
        , [Recording Audit]=MAX(CTE.[Recording Audit])
        , [Recorded Docs Requested]=MAX(CTE.[Recorded Docs Requested])
        , [Recorded Docs to Lender]=MAX(CTE.[Recorded Docs to Lender])
        , [Recorded Docs to Purchaser]=MAX(CTE.[Recorded Docs to Purchaser])
        , [TP to Lender]=MAX(CTE.[TP to Lender])
        , [TP Purchaser]=MAX(CTE.[TP Purchaser])
    FROM   CTE
    GROUP BY [OrderNo]
          , [CPC Emp]
    ORDER BY [CPC Emp];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to group by order number only and add aggregates to the fields that are not in the group by